# macOS Mojave (10.14) - how to get a full installer without using the macOS Mojave Patcher Tool

Tags: install, mac-appstore, mojave

I just want to install macOS Mojave (10.14) on one of my Macs without an internet connection. Therefore, I need an "offline" installer.

With previous versions of macOS I used the `createinstallmedia` command without any problems. However, this time I can't use this because when I download the installer from the Mac App Store on another Mac I only get a file that is 22 MBs in size.

I am aware of the "macOS Mojave Patcher Tool" but for my own reasons do not want to use this.

**In summary, how do I create/obtain an offline installer without having to use the macOS Mojave Patcher Tool in a situation that downloading from the Mac App Store isn't possible?**

Comment: Why don’t you trust macOS Mojave Patcher? A lot of people recommend it

Comment: I've edited your question to change it somewhat so that it isn't a duplicate of the other one. As it was, although the other one wasn't *fully answered* in your eyes, that doesn't change the fact that the question itself was a duplicate of your question as originally asked. Please feel free to edit your question again if you feel my edit has changed it too much.

Comment: What are the reasons that you do not want to use that tool? That reason could also apply to other tools.

Comment: @Mark because... just... why?  download.. i need wget or curl...  why is some third party software even necessary?

Comment: I agree with Michael here, especially in a business environment, third party software and guis shouldn't be necessary to get an image for an OS. I'm in a situation where I need to upgrade right now, but there's a bug in App Store, and we can't use unauthorized software to install an OS

Answer (score 5):

Link from Apple to create offline installer:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

Under "Download macOS" there are links in blue to macOS Catalina, macOS Mojave, macOS High Sierra, etc.

Click the link & scroll down to step 4 - the link to download your desired OS will open the app store & bring you to the download page.

**Note:** you need to [open the link on macOS using Safari](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251255597) for it to work properly.

Comment: Sorry, but that links leads me in a circle through another page on "How to upgrade to macOS Mojave" which takes me back to the App Store which is how I got stuck with this 22MB non-full installer to begin with.  Is there another link I am missing?  If so, please post the real link to how to download the full installer.

Comment: Works for me to pull a clean Mojave 10.4.6 full installer, via the App sStore *and* Software Update. Very bizarre and byzantine way to make installers available but it is possible to get them.

Comment: This no longer works for everything before Catalina. When you're redirected to the App Store, it will give you the message "The requested version of macOS is not available."

Comment: This so crazy that you can not use another browser even if you choose to open link with app store...